# Vuetify 2.6.7 - applying custom classes on v-icon svg

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

The problem I'm facing right now seems like it happens because of a vuetify version upgrade (2.6.7)

Problem : the custom classes applied on the v-icon / svg tags are not applying (ex. custom width / color ) . Also, it messes with the position in some random cases

Example :

OLD :
[image: v-icon-old]

NEW :
[image]

From what I've noticed, until now, the body of the v-icon was structured like this :

```
<v-icon>
  <svg>$iconName</svg>
</v-icon>
```

Example :

[image]

Now, on 2.6.7, it is structured like this :

```
<v-icon>
  <span>
    <svg>$iconName</svg>
  </span>
</v-icon>
```

Example :

[image]

I mention the fact that I've already tried to apply the custom class directly on the span child of the v-icon tag, but it dosen't work anymore :(

Anyone else faced this issue? If so, can you give me a tip on how to make the custom classes functional again?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried using deep css selector?

Comment: No, since the style isn't scoped for my component and from what I know, deep can only be used when the style is scoped.